# Javascript "ball" bouncing

Tags: javascript, html

I am a JS noob.  I am getting into browser game programming and wanted to make a quick example of a ball dropping and bouncing just to learn.  For some reason, when I created a jsfiddle my code actually didn't work, the onclick event for my div id="ball" didn't seem to be attaching, but when I run it in my browser it does.  But that is not my question.

In this code, the user clicks the ball, which is just a div with a black bg.  The div then follows the users cursor, and when the user clicks a second time, the div begins to fall towards the bottom of the window.  When it hits the bottom, it should bounce back up, with an apex half the distance between the y coordinate of where it was originally dropped and the bottom of window.  So if it was dropped at y position 600 and the bottom of the page is 800, the apex for the first bounce should be 700.  The 2nd bounce, the apex would be 750.  3rd bounce, 775.  You get the idea.  Can someone help me a bit here?  I am guessing I need to increment a counter each time the ball hits the bottom?

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#ball {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
}
</style>
<script>

window.onload = function() {

    var ballClicked = false;
    var ballFalling = false;
    var ballX = 100;
    var ballY = 100;
    var timesBounced = 0;
    var bounceApex = 0;
    var startingDropHeight = 0;
    var intervalVar;
    var ball = document.getElementById("ball");
    ball.style.left = ballX;
    ball.style.top = ballY;

    ball.onclick = function() {
        if (ballClicked == false) {
            ballClicked = true;
        } else {
            ballClicked = false;
            ballFalling = true;
            startingDropHeight = ballY;
            intervalVar = setInterval(function(){dropBall()} , 5);
        }
    };

    document.onmousemove = function(e) {
        if (ballClicked == true) {
            ballX = e.pageX;
            ballY = e.pageY;
            ball.style.left = ballX;
            ball.style.top = ballY;
        }
    };

    function dropBall() {
        if (ballFalling == true) {
            ballY = ballY + 1;
            ball.style.top = ballY;
            if (ballY == window.innerHeight - 50) {
                timesBounced = timesBounced + 1;
                bounceApex = (startingDropHeight + (window.innerHeight - 50)) / 2;
                ballFalling = false;
                if (bounceApex > window.innerHeight - 50) {
                    clearInterval(intervalVar);
                }
            };
        } else {
            ballY = ballY - 1;
            ball.style.top = ballY;
            if (ballY == bounceApex) {
                ballFalling = true;
            };
        }
    };

};

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="ball"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding left and top styles, you need to specify the unit as well. So, instead of:

```
ball.style.left = 100;
```

it should be:

```
ball.style.left = "100px";
```

I've fixed that in your code and made a working jsfiddle, will improve the bouncing in a bit. See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/12grut99/

About the repetitive bouncing, this line is the issue:

```
bounceApex = (startingDropHeight + (window.innerHeight - 50)) / 2;
```

You're always calculating the apex based on the original drop height, yet after every bounce, the drop height should be the previous bounceApex (the highest point the ball reached).

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I'll take a look. Works fine on my FF33/Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you Shomz for the reply.  Like I said, I'm a self admitted JS noob :) Gotta start somewhere, and I know that about your edit.  If I make it 

bounceApex = (bounceApex + (window.innerHeight - 50)) / 2

Should I set bounceApex = originalDropHeight before calling setInterval? I think I tried that and got an undesirable result, but i'll try again.

Comment: Yes, that's a good direction. See it here, I've done a couple more fixes: http://jsfiddle.net/12grut99/1/ One of them was exactly that: `bounceApex = ((bounceApex || startingDropHeight) + (window.innerHeight - 50)) / 2;`

Comment: Doing what I just said kind of worked, but now I need to figure out how to call clearInterval once the bounce apex is close to the bottom of the window, because it's not being called after a few bounces so it starts going to the top after working as intended for a few bounces.

Comment: Yes, it's because you were checking like `ballY == bounceApex` which sometimes might not be true because of division by 2 (so you'd get `50 == 49.5` which would cause the ball to start flying upwards and never return... I changed it to `ballY <= bounceApex`. In that last version I sent you, you just need to figure out when to stop the bouncing, I believe your clearInterval check is off, but I'll let you fix that one yourself. :)

Comment: Ok great, you are a big help man, I truly appreciate it.  I can tell in that jsfiddle you just posted clearInterval is still not being called though, but I can figure it out.  Also when I look at the w3schools JS operators reference, it says | is logical OR, but can't find what || is.

Btw I marked your response as the answer.  :)

Comment: You're welcome! Best of luck with your future endeavours. Here, the stop bounce issue was the similar (`>` instead of `>=`): http://jsfiddle.net/12grut99/2/

Comment: | is a bitwise OR, || is logical OR. If you have `(first || second)` it will first check if `first` is truthy, if so, returns it; if not, it checks the same thing for `second`. See if this little example makes sense: http://jsfiddle.net/Lm3o0sjy/

Comment: Here is a much better reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

Comment: Nice, obviously I have a long way to go, but people such as yourself and this site make the process much easier :D

Comment: Just made it a bit more "naturally" jumping: http://jsfiddle.net/12grut99/5/ It misses some of the other changes but probably you can merge that.

Comment: @AxelAmthor It jumps insanely fast. The next big step in this would be the implementation of acceleration, gravity and rebound physics, some of which you have started, but some numbers definitely need tweaking.

Comment: @Shomz depends on height, cpu speed etc. Tweaking needs to be done, as well as some calc on acceleration / gravity, yes. That's basically an idea on how to proceed. Definitively not a finisched code.

Comment: @AxelAmthor Yeah, yeah, the inconsistencies of setInterval.